# Do I need a stereo digital microphone?

Tags: stereo, mems-microphone

I am working on a voice recording application. The circuit simply has microcontroller, flash memory and mems digital microphone.

What are the advantages of using a stereo microphone on the quality of sound? If necessary, how should I position these two microphones?

The application does not require localization, beamforming similar complex works, just simple sound recording.

Comment: What makes you think you might need a stereo microphone? Have you tried using a mono microphone?

Comment: Because it is very common in smartphones,laptops or headphones. I want to understand whether it is used to improve quality.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what stereo audio is / means?

Comment: As i understand, there're 2 physical mics on the device(called right and left), data acquiring over these 2 channel and doing some processing like mixing with software, the actual sound is taken.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the advantages of using a stereo microphone on the quality of sound?

The advantage of a stereo microphone (or two mono microphones) is that it is possible to record in stereo for reproduction of a stereophonic image with sound sources located in the audio panorama. There is no advantage in fidelity of signal or signal to noise ratio.

> If necessary, how should I position these two microphones?

Position them to get the effect you require. This is a broad subject so I will not attempt to answer it here as there is plenty of information on the web.

Comment: "There is no advantage in fidelity of signal or signal to noise ratio." - Not always correct: You can use two microphones to do beam forming, increasing relative sensitivity in one direction while decreasing in another.